# i try to get data from api but when there is null there, after first null i get null after it

Tags: flutter, api, dart

there is null there, after first null I get nulls after it, cause it got caught but exception, how to make exception?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfzLH.png). As you can see in picture, vehichles and starship are null, and caught by exeption, after them there is 3 data, they become null too. When i remove vehichles and starship everything is ok
How to make it ? I wanna get null for vehichles and starship and get data normally after them(Soryy for my English)

```
Future<dynamic> getSwData() async{
   return await MyStarWarsService().getDataFromSWApi().then((value) async{
     if(value != null){
       setState((){
        name = value!.name!;
         height = value!.height!;
         mass = value!.mass!;
         birth_year = value!.birth_year!;
         eye_color = value!.eye_color!;
         films = value!.films!;
         gender = value!.gender!;
         hair_color = value!.hair_color!;
         homeworld = value!.homeworld!;
         skin_color = value!.skin_color!;
         vehicles = value.vehcles; //// it is NULL
         starships = value.starsips;// it is NUll
         species = value!.species!;/// NOT null
         created = value!.created!;//// NOT null but come NUll
         edited = value!.edited!;//// NOT null but come NULL
         url = value!.url!;//// NOT null, but come NULL

       });
       return value;
     }
   },
   ).catchError((_){
     throw Exception("Exception is caught"); this exception caught null and after it everithings become null
   });
  }
}
```

HTTP 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
"name": "C-3PO",
"height": "167",
"mass": "75",
"hair_color": "n/a",
"skin_color": "gold",
"eye_color": "yellow",
"birth_year": "112BBY",
"gender": "n/a",
"homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/",
"films": [
"https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/",
"https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/",
"https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/",
"https://swapi.dev/api/films/4/",
"https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/",
"https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
],
"species": [
"https://swapi.dev/api/species/2/"
],
"vehicles": [], it null

```
"starships": [], it is null 



"created": "2014-12-10T15:10:51.357000Z", afetr i get nulls for this but it is not null
"edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.309000Z", 
"url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/2/"
```

}

Comment: We need to see the Exception and probably also the code of `getDataFromSWApi`

Comment: Exception in the code

Comment: We need to see the code of `getDataFromSWApi` where the exception actually is thrown and then catched in the code presented here. Without seeing the code and probably also the original Exception it is a guessing game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am struggling to understand the question (poor English), but it seems like you want to accept null as the value if it I null. If that's true, using the ! after the value tells the code that you are sure there is a non null value. Change the ! to ? to allow null.
For example:
 `name = value!.name!;`
becomes
 `name = value.name?;`
Name can now have a null value.

I suggest you research null safety.

Comment: look at the image I attach, vehicles and starship are null and get caught by exception. It is ok. But after vehicles and starship, there are 3 data, and i got nulls for the last 3 data, but there are not nulls. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Please provide the API exception, not your exception

Comment: But i got caught by this exception. I dont have any other exception. And there is one for connection(if connection is Not 200)

Comment: So then it looks like there isn't a problem. If the value is null, it will be set to null.

Comment: but the last 3 data (created = value!.created!
         edited = value!.edited!
         url = value!.url!;) I get nulls for them , but there ar NOT null.

Comment: If it's not null then what is it? Maybe you have a typo. Show the code of getDataFromSWApi. You are not providing enough info to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I updated the question a little

Comment: That's good, but I have no idea what you added. I see it, but I don't know what it is

Comment: I mean why after vehicles and starship(the are null) i get nulls for CREATED, EDITED and URL(they are strings not null)

Answer (score 0):

If you use async and await in your future and at the end SetState after Then, you will need to check the mounted in the tree like that :

```
Future<dynamic> getSwData() async{
   return await MyStarWarsService().getDataFromSWApi().then((value){

     if(this.mounted){

       // add your SetState

     }
    
   }  
     
 }
```

This is a good habit to do.